# How to disable code execution until tween complete?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hi guys i am using Phaser 3.5 and wanted to stop this click function from executing if the tween is still ongoing?

```
game.input.on("pointerdown", function(pointer) {
  game.tweens.add({
    targets: playerHands,
    angle: 20,
    duration: 1000,
    yoyo: true
  });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Add a flag variable. Check it on click. If it's set, return immediately. If it's not set, set it and run the tween. At the end of the tween (`onComplete`), unset the flag.

Comment: @Ouroborus do you have an example of this? I have tried variations before but all have failed so far.

Answer (score 0):

A flag variable would be something like:

```
game.canTweenFlag = true;
game.input.on("pointerdown", function(pointer) {
if(game.canTweenFlag) {
  game.canTweenFlag = false;
  game.tweens.add({
    targets: playerHands,
    angle: 20,
    duration: 1000,
    yoyo: true,
    onComplete: function () { game.canTweenFlag = true; }
  });
}
});
```